# Django Apache configuration static files

Tags: python, django, apache

I've a little issue concerning the configuration of Django and Apache on AWS Lightsail.

I followed this guide: https://aws.amazon.com/it/getting-started/hands-on/deploy-python-application/ 
point 5) Host the application using Apache
I configured all the files just like the guide states (obviously using the name of my prj instead of "template").

Everything is working except the static files: ie. I see my website without any css/img/js files.

Must I add something in urls.py? in settings.py? I feel I've tried everything...

How can I correctly configure Apache? For me it's the first time dealing with Django and Apache, and I cannot find a guide that works for my situation.

This is my tree of the prj:
[tree-prj-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isqj5.png)

Thank you,
Manuel

Comment: did you run the command `python manage.py collectstatics`?

Comment: yes I already ran it.. it created a folder myproject/static.. I think that the problem is the right configuration of this folder both on bitnami conf file and on httpd-app.conf, but I tried all solutions found on internet without solved it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.. I just spent all night for just few lines of code ahah
I add the following lines to my file urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
   urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```